# How can I fix the width of text in ReportLab when printing to PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm new to ReportLab. I want to print a string in my PDF in fixed width. That is, if the string is longer than the width, it will go to the second line automatically. How can I do this?

Here is my code, and [strange result](http://pinwecard.com/statics/hello.pdf). I don't know how to fix it...

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import XBox

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
x = XBox(width=50, height=100, text='abcaf a dsfadf asdfafasf  sdfa adsf asdf asdf afasdf df asdf asf asdf asfdsf asss')
f = Frame(x1=150, y1=50, width=200, height=200)
f.add(x, c)
c.save()
```

Comment: Maybe using a [table](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/platypus.html#module-reportlab.platypus.tables) with a single column where you define the **width of the column**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to approach this is to use Platypus and put your text inside Paragraph flowables. If you don't use Platypus you'll have to take care of doing the line wrap calculations yourself.

Comment: Hi, I add some code in my original post. Can you help me out?